# Transform element with given 4 points to another 4 points

Tags: css, transform

How can I calculate CSS transformation to make div with given 4 points to be fit to another 4 points? Is it really possible?

I need function something like:

```
$el.css("transform", generateTransform(p1, p2, p3, p4, pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4));
```

[image]

Comment: try with `transform:skew(160deg,160deg);`

Comment: The response by Honza to this thread on math.stackexchange seems to exactly answer your question:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186286/get-transformation-matrix-from-points/

You only need two points, and it's just a matter of algebra. The question was about 3D perspective transformations, but Honza conveniently misinterpreted the question to be about 2D transforms.

Comment: @Abram, Im sure I need 4 points if I want arbitrary transformation. There is not an affine transformation that I need.